# Calling one file from another file gives print value instead of return return value in perl

Tags: perl

I can execute one Perl file from another Perl file using the command

```
`perl -X file-path -arguments=value`
```

but this gives the print value from the file instead of giving the return value.

This is `abc.pl`:

```
my $a = `perl -X def.pl -num=4`;
print "here a is $a";
```

This is `def.pl`:

```
print "in def file";
my $xy = "hello world!";
return $xy;
```

When invoke the file as `perl -X abc.pl`, I expect the output to be

```
here a is hello world!
```

but I am getting

```
Can't return outside a subroutine at def.pl line 3.
here a is in def file
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: See [perldoc perlmod](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod#Perl-Modules) for how to use Perl code from other Perl code.

Comment: I added the error message you got but didn't tell us about

Answer (score 2):

[`-X` suppresses warnings.](http://p3rl.org/run#-X) Don't suppress them, they give the hint why the code is failing your expectations.

You should be using subroutines and libraries.

*def.pl*

```
sub hello {
    print "in def file\n";
    my $xy = "hello world!";
    return $xy;
}
1;
```

*abc.pl*

```
require './def.pl';
my $a = hello();
print "here a is $a";
```

Next step up from here is organising your code as modules.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `` `command` `` in Perl, the result is the standard output of the called command. This is similar to shell similar syntax.

Given 'def.pl' is perl program, you can execute it directly from abc.pl, using 'require'. However, 'def.pl' must be a valid perl program. Executing 'return $xy' outside a function will result in error message: Can't return outside a subroutine at - line 1.

Consider creating a function in 'def.pl' that returns the value of $xy. The alternative, which is less than ideal, is to use global.

```
# abc.pl
require 'def.pl' ;
my $a = xy() ;
print "here a is $a";


# def.pl
sub xy {
    my $xy = "..." ;
    return $xy ;
}
```

Alternatively, you can make def.pl 'print' the result, making it possible to retrieve the 'result' from the def.pl script.

```
# def.pl
warn "in def file";
my $xy = "hello world!";
print $xy;
```